# How To Get The Distinct Values From 2 columns Into 1

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say I have a table, table1.

And table1 has 2 columns, "**Vegetables**" and "**Fruits**"

Using the values from table 1, how can I get the distinct of these 2 columns and use them to create a new column in a new table?

Attached is a sample table of input values, and expected output

I am using snowflake.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO table2 (name)
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT vegetables AS name FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT fruits AS name FROM table1
) AS names
GROUP BY name;
```

Check this out --> [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bce7302/1)

Comment: wouldnt this have duplicates? if we are taking all the fruits, apple repeats 2x

Comment: Did you try? @VoidS

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM
(
  SELECT fruits AS column_name FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT vegetables AS column_name FROM table2
) AS distinct_values;
```